# Assembly JP / JNP to C code

Tags: c, assembly

How would I go about converting a assembly snippet like this to C code, without any ASM inlining as I would like to convert it to .NET too.

JP example..

```
seg000:0041FA29                 jp      short near ptr loc_41FA2B+2
seg000:0041FA2B
seg000:0041FA2B loc_41FA2B:                             ; CODE XREF: seg000:0041FA29j
seg000:0041FA2B                 mov     eax, 104E8B00h
seg000:0041FA30                 mov     eax, ebx
```

JNP example

```
seg000:0041FB8B                 mov     eax, 0x40F009
seg000:0041FB90                 sub     [ebp-18h], eax
seg000:0041FB93                 jnp     short near ptr loc_41FB95+2
seg000:0041FB95
seg000:0041FB95 loc_41FB95:                             ; CODE XREF: seg000:0041FB93j
seg000:0041FB95                 mov     eax, 1C468B00h
```

I noticed these opcodes behave pretty stange in IDA PRO like they alter themselves.. I dont know how to explain this but they become different instructions when you run them..

At first I stepped them and Nopped them out thinking it was some sort of obfuscation.. But it turns out to be something pretty interesting probably optimized code.

I know they are same like Jumps JE/JMP/JNZ etc.. But they don't deal with registers but with flag for overflow checking how I transform this into C code?

I thought then maybe it was like this,

JP example

```
   int eax = 0x4E8688;
   ebp_18 |= eax;
   if(ebp_18 % 2)
     eax = ebx;
   else
     eax = 0x104E8B00;
```

JNP example

```
   int eax = 0x40F009;
   ebp_18 = eax;
   if(!(ebp_18 % 1))
     ebp_18 -= eax;
   else
     eax = 0x1C468B00;
```

Whats worse I cannot even step this line by line in ollydebugger or IDA PRO because it keeps modifying the instructions in realtime

Bytes:

> 55 8B EC 6A FF 68 D0 58 4A 00 64 A1 00 00 00 00 50 64 89 25 00 00 00
>   00 83 EC 1C 53 56 57 8B F1 89 65 F0 89 55 E4 89 75 EC C7 45 FC 00 00
>   00 00 7A 03 7B 03 C7 7B FB 8B 7E 1C 8B 5E 2C 8B 56 34 33 FB 33 FA C7
>   45 E8 95 3B 58 3A 83 E7 0F 83 FF 07 75 37 B8 80 05 42 00 2D F0 5C 00
>   00 BA A1 50 36 F4 8B 4D EC FF D0 F7 D8 05 3A 4A 17 08 BA 18 AC 52 82
>   8B 4D EC FF D0 F7 D8 05 55 44 6A 21 89 45 E0 8B 56 20 8B CE FF 55 E0
>   83 FF 04 75 37 B8 70 3B 42 00 2D F0 9E 00 00 BA 35 48 BB E6 8B 4D EC
>   FF D0 F7 D8 05 58 C7 8E 0A BA B0 A4 8C 72 8B 4D EC FF D0 F7 D8 05 7F
>   C6 61 1D 89 45 E0 8B 56 1C 8B CE FF 55 E0 B8 21 4F 4B 00 29 45 E8 7A
>   02 B8 00 8B 5E 18 8B 4D E8 03 D9 0F AF 5D E4 85 FF 89 5D E4 75 37 B8
>   90 B0 41 00 2D 80 0E 00 00 BA 66 25 11 EF 8B 4D EC FF D0 F7 D8 05 52
>   2A A9 17 BA 5D DB 73 DD 8B 4D EC FF D0 F7 D8 05 FC 37 78 0B 89 45 E0
>   8B 56 34 8B CE FF 55 E0 83 FF 03 75 36 B8 80 B4 41 00 2D 80 16 00 00
>   BA 56 38 38 43 8B 4D EC FF D0 F7 D8 05 92 1B 7C 00 BA ED 14 2F EA 8B
>   4D EC FF D0 F7 D8 05 68 81 D5 06 89 45 E0 8B D3 8B CE FF 55 E0 83 FF
>   04 75 36 B8 D0 C9 41 00 2D 60 23 00 00 BA 84 2C 04 D8 8B 4D EC FF D0
>   F7 D8 05 CF C0 F2 2D BA 26 D0 C0 33 8B 4D EC FF D0 F7 D8 05 B1 B3 6E
>   07 89 45 E0 8B D3 8B CE FF 55 E0 B8 2D 51 46 00 01 45 E8 7B 02 B8 00
>   8B 06 C7 45 E0 00 00 00 00 25 FF 00 00 00 89 45 DC DF 6D DC D9 FE DC
>   1D B8 91 4A 00 DF E0 F6 C4 01 8B 45 E8 75 03 8B 46 08 8B 4E 08 2B C8
>   83 FF 08 89 4E 08 75 37 B8 20 57 42 00 2D A0 AD 00 00 BA ED 0D F1 39
>   8B 4D EC FF D0 F7 D8 05 9F 37 9C 24 BA 30 FB 56 D3 8B 4D EC FF D0 F7
>   D8 05 92 46 66 00 89 45 E0 8B 56 24 8B CE FF 55 E0 83 FF 02 75 36 B8
>   70 BD 41 00 2D C0 1B 00 00 BA 27 17 9E D4 8B 4D EC FF D0 F7 D8 05 16
>   10 BA 01 BA 2B E4 43 DD 8B 4D EC FF D0 F7 D8 05 52 62 43 36 89 45 E0
>   8B D3 8B CE FF 55 E0 8B 4D E8 8B D3 D3 C2 8B 4E 38 03 CA 83 FF 05 89
>   4E 38 75 36 B8 F0 12 42 00 2D D0 6E 00 00 BA C7 BD 5E 4D 8B 4D EC FF
>   D0 F7 D8 05 3D FB 97 74 BA 45 B1 48 FF 8B 4D EC FF D0 F7 D8 05 4E F7
>   24 09 89 45 E0 8B D3 8B CE FF 55 E0 83 FF 0F 75 37 B8 40 F9 41 00 2D
>   B0 50 00 00 BA 64 3F CF FA 8B 4D EC FF D0 F7 D8 05 1F 3B BE 0C BA 06
>   F2 FE CE 8B 4D EC FF D0 F7 D8 05 F9 87 A7 02 89 45 E0 8B 56 34 8B CE
>   FF 55 E0 85 FF 75 37 B8 F0 37 42 00 2D 50 9C 00 00 BA 33 9F FF 77 8B
>   4D EC FF D0 F7 D8 05 ED 30 75 02 BA 22 12 AB 2B 8B 4D EC FF D0 F7 D8
>   05 65 38 C9 2A 89 45 E0 8B 56 48 8B CE FF 55 E0 B8 56 11 4A 00 29 45
>   E8 7A 02 B8 00 8B 46 08 8B 4E 04 C1 C8 2A 03 C8 83 FF 06 89 4E 04 75
>   37 B8 D0 D8 41 00 2D E0 38 00 00 BA D2 B7 41 7D 8B 4D EC FF D0 F7 D8
>   05 BE 4A 08 46 BA 09 63 01 19 8B 4D EC FF D0 F7 D8 05 AE 75 31 27 89
>   45 E0 8B 56 30 8B CE FF 55 E0 83 FF 05 75 37 B8 A0 2F 42 00 2D 10 8C
>   00 00 BA 3E B1 68 38 8B 4D EC FF D0 F7 D8 05 87 8A 52 4F BA ED 64 32
>   38 8B 4D EC FF D0 F7 D8 05 90 3D DB 02 89 45 E0 8B 56 28 8B CE FF 55
>   E0 B8 26 03 4B 00 09 45 E8 7A 02 B8 00 8B 4E 48 C7 45 E0 00 00 00 00
>   8B D1 81 E2 FF 00 00 00 89 55 DC DF 6D DC D9 FF DC 1D B8 91 4A 00 DF
>   E0 F6 C4 01 8B 45 E8 75 03 8B 46 38 2B C8 83 FF 0A 89 4E 48 75 37 B8
>   70 57 42 00 2D 10 B9 00 00 BA E6 41 C8 1C 8B 4D EC FF D0 F7 D8 05 DE
>   4B C7 0B BA A4 2B B2 0F 8B 4D EC FF D0 F7 D8 05 6E CC 6D 43 89 45 E0
>   8B 56 38 8B CE FF 55 E0 83 FF 01 75 6D B8 90 F4 41 00 2D B0 57 00 00
>   BA B7 F4 83 F7 8B 4D EC FF D0 F7 D8 05 8D EC E0 24 BA 07 0C F1 F2 8B
>   4D EC FF D0 F7 D8 05 03 70 70 13 89 45 E0 8B 56 08 8B CE FF 55 E0 B8
>   50 C5 41 00 2D F0 1C 00 00 BA 2C 0D A6 89 8B 4D EC FF D0 F7 D8 05 56
>   7D 64 28 BA E5 B2 75 76 8B 4D EC FF D0 F7 D8 05 4F 3E 2E 3B 89 45 E0
>   8B D3 8B CE FF 55 E0 8B 46 3C 8B 56 40 8D 0C 40 C1 E1 03 2B C8 F7 D9
>   D1 E1 03 D1 83 FF 0C 89 56 40 75 36 B8 A0 11 42 00 2D 60 76 00 00 BA
>   13 97 03 AE 8B 4D EC FF D0 F7 D8 05 5D B7 5E 27 BA 60 25 FE F9 8B 4D
>   EC FF D0 F7 D8 05 EF 9B 1C 05 89 45 E0 8B D3 8B CE FF 55 E0 83 FF 09
>   75 36 B8 D0 61 42 00 2D F0 C6 00 00 BA 46 B7 54 E3 8B 4D EC FF D0 F7
>   D8 05 C5 94 03 23 BA AF C6 A3 DD 8B 4D EC FF D0 F7 D8 05 88 3B 83 38
>   89 45 E0 8B D3 8B CE FF 55 E0 B8 2D 99 46 00 21 45 E8 7B 02 B8 00 0F
>   9F DB 8B 46 08 8B 4E 10 8D 14 C0 8D 04 90 8D 04 40 03 C8 83 FF 06 89
>   4E 10 75 37 B8 A0 4F 42 00 2D F0 B2 00 00 BA B5 12 5F DE 8B 4D EC FF
>   D0 F7 D8 05 61 7F 90 38 BA 6F 86 71 46 8B 4D EC FF D0 F7 D8 05 0B D2
>   C5 2A 89 45 E0 8B 56 44 8B CE FF 55 E0 83 FF 02 75 37 B8 A0 AA 41 00
>   2D 00 0A 00 00 BA 31 5A 5C F8 8B 4D EC FF D0 F7 D8 05 A4 E3 FF 1D BA
>   1B 9E 8D AB 8B 4D EC FF D0 F7 D8 05 C8 E1 37 34 89 45 E0 8B 56 28 8B
>   CE FF 55 E0 83 FF 0B 75 37 B8 70 48 42 00 2D B0 9D 00 00 BA 12 0B D6
>   72 8B 4D EC FF D0 F7 D8 05 9F 86 B4 00 BA D4 7F 57 E0 8B 4D EC FF D0
>   F7 D8 05 52 56 30 51 89 45 E0 8B 56 38 8B CE FF 55 E0 B8 46 93 48 00
>   09 45 E8 7B 02 B8 00 8B 46 44 8B 4E 0C 8B 56 4C C1 E1 06 0B D1 83 FF
>   03 89 56 4C 75 37 B8 A0 F8 41 00 2D 20 4F 00 00 BA 73 0A 63 F9 8B 4D
>   EC FF D0 F7 D8 05 AE F9 FB 67 BA BE 6B 95 37 8B 4D EC FF D0 F7 D8 05
>   7D 24 78 02 89 45 E0 8B 56 08 8B CE FF 55 E0 83 FF 0E 75 36 B8 20 6A
>   42 00 2D 60 C1 00 00 BA C2 F6 D8 04 8B 4D EC FF D0 F7 D8 05 AC 5E 3D
>   0F BA 15 B8 2D 87 8B 4D EC FF D0 F7 D8 05 2E F0 EC 1C 89 45 E0 8B D3
>   8B CE FF 55 E0 8B 46 20 8B 4D E8 3B C1 72 02 8B C3 8B 4E 30 23 C8 83
>   FF 07 89 4E 30 75 37 B8 00 E2 41 00 2D 80 3A 00 00 BA 60 B3 48 A7 8B
>   4D EC FF D0 F7 D8 05 38 6F B0 38 BA AA 10 45 FF 8B 4D EC FF D0 F7 D8
>   05 AC 6C 0C 1C 89 45 E0 8B 56 2C 8B CE FF 55 E0 83 FF 0D 75 36 B8 B0
>   4F 42 00 2D 20 A7 00 00 BA CC 0C 35 F6 8B 4D EC FF D0 F7 D8 05 F7 81
>   18 02 BA 02 78 86 E9 8B 4D EC FF D0 F7 D8 05 33 92 7B 01 89 45 E0 8B
>   16 8B CE FF 55 E0 B8 E6 6C 4B 00 09 45 E8 7A 02 B8 00 8B 46 38 8B 4E
>   44 8B C3 35 06 98 44 07 2B C8 8B C3 89 4E 44 8B 4D F4 64 89 0D 00 00
>   00 00 5F 5E 5B 8B E5 5D C3 8B 55 D8 8B 45 E4 33 C2 89 45 E4 B8 6A 1C
>   42 00 C3 8B 5D E4 8B 4D F4 5F 8B C3 5E 64 89 0D 00 00 00 00 5B 8B E5
>   5D C3

Comment: Where did the assembly code come from? That could be helpful. Also if it's modifying itself during runtime its probably a compiler optimization (I hope because self modifying code is a big no no most of the time)

Comment: How legal is what you're trying to do?

Comment: Well it's a game, wasted 5 days got passed 13k asm lines and this stumped me

Comment: Hahaha.. the owner of this program did state he had custom protection it with military style encryption. Sure i'll edit the question and add the bytes.. but it's huge.. i'll add the first function.. this is repeated over 128 functions which are all similar to this.

Comment: Btw if you guys want to know.. the maker of this snippet is also one of the founders of Skype this is one of his abandoned projects

Comment: In non-obfuscated compiler output, most JP/JNP instructions follow FP comparisons like [UCOMISD](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/UCOMISD.html) (to detect NaN / unordered comparison results).  The first code block is pretty dumb, because it doesn't show what's setting PF, so it's impossible to write a C equivalent (because C doesn't have flags).  However, since on closer inspection this is for obfuscation, PF is probably set from integer instructions like in the second block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is definitely obfuscation code. Look at the destination of the jump:

```
    jp      short near ptr loc_41FA2B+2
loc_41FA2B:
    mov     eax, 104E8B00h
```

Notice that the destination of the jump is 2 bytes into the next instruction. This means that the actual instruction you should be looking at starts two bytes in. The machine code of the `mov` instruction would be `B8 00 8B 4E 10`. If you skip the first two bytes, you have `8B 4E 10`. The disassembly of this is:

```
mov ecx,[esi+16]
```

The calculation before the `jp` instruction must have a known result so that the proper instruction is used. Since NOPing it failed, I will assume that the calculation should result in the parity flag being set. This means that you could get the right result by NOPing the `jp` instruction and the first 2 bytes of the `mov` instruction.

The second snippet is the same type of thing, except that the result of the calculation should have the parity flag cleared. After skipping the first two bytes, the disassembly is:

```
mov eax,[esi+28]
```

Comment: yeah but meh there is like 4 per function x 128 = 512 changes I gotta do by hand, thats a lot of work lol, So I have to look for B8 00's and pretty much somehow remove them? I tried nopping as well. Logic got messed up

Comment: You mentioned using IDA, so you have the option of using IDC and Python to fix this stuff automatically.

Comment: So I always just remove 2 bytes or until 8B is found? http://pastebin.com/LrtgBkEj (This one looks like 3 bytes?)

Comment: @SSpoke Yes, the second one should be 3 bytes. The trick is to look at the number of bytes after the start of the instruction the jump goes to. The first jump is `jno short near ptr loc_41F936+2`. Note the `+2` at the end. The jump goes two bytes into the label, so you do two `nop`s. The second is `jnb short near ptr loc_419F8A+3`. Since this one has a `+3` instead, it goes 3 bytes into the instruction and you should use three `nop`s.

Comment: how about this one.. http://pastebin.com/chqkn9be  its +1 and +3.. and looks complicated where to start both start at 410D7? so remove 4? `[7A 03] [7B 03] [E9 7B FB 8D 82] [CB] [33 49 19] [35 A8 B7 1B 0C]`
maybe I got to add up 1+3=4 and remove 4 after both opcodes like so
`[7A 03 7B 03] [90 90 90 90 82] [CB] [33 49 19] [35 A8 B7 1B 0C]` still doesn't look right so opcode turns to 82

Comment: @SSpoke That one's interesting. If the calculation before set the parity bit, it would jump one byte in. Otherwise it would jump 3 in. But the instruction one byte in is a `jnp` instruction, which takes two bytes, and obviously won't be followed since the parity bit has to be set to get there. So you can `nop` either 1 or 3 and it should work.

Comment: i nopped 1 and got http://pastebin.com/QJvdEcJ6 yeah.. is this a known obfuscation technique any tools to strip all of this out available?

Comment: @SSpoke All of your `nop`s should go after the label IDA originally puts in, so you would put the 1 `nop` on the `jmp` instruction instead of the `jnp` instruction (you could `nop` the `jp` and `jnp` instructions completely too, if you wanted, but that doesn't make a difference). There aren't any tools that I know of. If you need any more help on this, we should probably take it to chat instead of the comments.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Lz2uff2z i dont want to waste your time chat is unnecessary. I got it anyways I believe

Comment: Well I thought I understood it all by now but these 2 examples have me guessing.. probably the last question I have to ask you. You don't have to explain it to be.. just show me how you patch it bytes.. i'll find out what you did myself. Here here it is : http://pastebin.com/VQrKaSDq

Comment: @SSpoke It looks like IDA helped you with those. I think the non-instruction byte in the middle of each was probably obfuscation to change the instructions. The first you can `nop` all the way through the `jp/jnp`s, but you should leave the second as is (it looks like it could be part of position independent code).

Comment: second as in CALL example? so the CALL one should not be modified? So on the first one is just `mov dword ptr [ebp-4], 0`     `mov edi, [esi+1Ch]`  Well I'm doing this so I would be able to decompile it with Hex-rays without any problems.. so then I could see C code how it really works.  I don't know that CALL example looks like the CALL is useless

Comment: You'll probably want to `nop` the `db 0B8h`, but other than that, yeah.

Comment: Thanks i'll remove byte `B8` although it looks like a call or something lol.. here is a full example of another CALL obfuscation.. same thing? remove byte `9A`? http://pastebin.com/RC0BpTLH

Comment: I think I got it.. that db 0B8h.. is just a random byte it puts in.. thinking it would trick ollyDbg/IDA Pro.. to screw up the code flow yeah? wow thats some nice trickery i think i understand it now, thanks again mate.

Answer (score 0):

The Intel documentation says that `jp` jumps if the parity flag is set. `jnp` jumps if the parity flag is *not* set. The parity flag is set if the least significant byte of the result of a previous instruction contains an even number of 1 bits.

For more information, see Intel order number 24319002.

Comment: That's how integer instructions set PF, but other instructions can set it differently.  In real code, it's a lot more common to see JP/JNP used after floating-point comparisons like [UCOMISD](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/UCOMISD.html) (to detect NaN / unordered comparison results).  The OP's first code block is pretty dumb, because it doesn't show what's setting PF, so it's impossible to write a C equivalent.